# How do I make Beautiful Soup find the specific div?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
import pandas as pd  # Pandas is used for data manipulation and analysis
import datetime  # Manipulating date and times
import requests  # Allows for making HTTPS requests to websites
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # Beautiful Soup used for web scraping, particularly HTML and XML documents
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# Function to find the value inside the url (url content)
def web_content_div(web_content, class_path):
    # Find the div from the web_content with a specific class path
    web_content_div = web_content.findAll('div', {"class": class_path})
    print(web_content_div)
    try:
        # Find all the spans within the dive
        spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
        texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
        print(spans)
    except IndexError:
        texts = []
    return texts


def real_time_price(stock_code):
    # Locate the information
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?.tsrc=fin-srch'

    # See if there is anything we can get from the url
    try:
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        # Capture the text from the url
        web_content = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        # print("Web Content: " + str(web_content))

        # Parse the text into the web function
        texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'bottom svelte-okyrr7')
        driver.close()

        if texts:
            price, change = texts[0], texts[1]
        else:
            price, change = [], []

    except ConnectionError:
        price, change = [], []

    return price, change


Stock = ["BRK-B"]
print(real_time_price('BRK-B'))
```

Im making a program which would give stock updates in real time. I made this starter program to reflect the stock price from yahoo finance for Berkshire Hathaway. The span containing the price and price change lie in the parent div class bottom svelte-okyrr7. However, it seems that this line:

`web_content_div = web_content.findAll('div', {"class": class_path})`

Is not able to locate that div at all. What am I doing wrong?

I tried directly using the div class under which both spans existed but that didn't work either. I am not sure how I could make the the findAll() method actually find the div and extract the spans from it. Even Selenium isn't helping (unless im using it incorrectly)

Comment: We can't tell because we don't what the HTML you're trying to scrape looks like. Also, chances are that what you're trying to do violates the terms of service of the site.

Comment: @AndyLester there is a tutorial on this using the same website on youtube which was uploaded 3 years ago with 100k+ views so I don't think it violates the terms of service

Comment: So I was able to get it to work but I want it headless but it doesn't seem to work on headless :/

Comment: can you edit the question and provide a reference to the page you are trying to scrape? since you haven't shared a sample it's impossible to tell what is the issue. code looks correct to me, though. since you mention in your comment it doesn't work "headless" it could be the content is dynamically emitted via javascript (the major difference of headless is no page evaluations occur, ie. no resource loads nor script executions.)